# How can one RDP from a Samsung M8 Smart Monitor to a Windows 11 Azure VM?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, azure

Due to the below error, I cannot connect to the Windows 11 desktop in Azure from my M8 smart monitor.

Error: ***Workspace cannot connect to the remote PC. Make sure the remote PC is turned on, connected to the Internet and remote access enabled. You cannot connect if the PC's in sleep mode.***

[image: userT46SsSZzm8_0-1658694112221.png]

Samsung Support did not know what to do and said I needed to do a factory reset and get a replacement. Remote desktop connection to another desktop in the same Wi-Fi network is working fine. So I am guessing this is an external name resolution or routing-related connectivity problem. Is there a way to connect to a virtual machine in Azure from one's smart monitor over the Internet?
https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/smart-monitors/32-m8-4k-smart-monitor-and-streaming-tv-white-ls32bm801unxgo/

Comment: Have you checked that on that Windows 11 computer [enabled Remote Desktop on Windows 11](https://pureinfotech.com/enable-remote-desktop-windows-11/)?

Comment: Yes, @harrymc. I'm able to RDP to the Windows 11 Azure VM from all other devices.

Comment: Might be a firewall issue, or perhaps the TV doesn't have the right cypher to connect securely.

Comment: The smart monitor spec documents it's capable of connecting to a Microsoft cloud workspace. However, Samsung doesn't document how. It's not a TV though. I believe the cipher is there since it is able to RDP to other devices connected to the same WiFi network, using `PCName.attlocal.net`. Since my WiFi network is controlled thru the AT&T router. However, the Azure VM has a public IP. I think it's a routing or DNS resolution related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to M8 Smart monitor Firmware version 1304 resolved the issue.